# Move borderless form in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

In VCL forms I use **WM_SYSCOMMAND**, but in firemonkey it is undeclared.

I test this code:

```
procedure TForm4.dragPanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  isDraging := true;
  X0 := X;
  Y0 := Y;
end;

procedure TForm4.dragPanelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Single);
begin
  if isDraging then
  begin
    Form4.Left := Trunc(Form4.Left + X - X0);
    Form4.Top := Trunc(Form4.Top + Y - Y0);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.dragPanelMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  isDraging := False;
end;
```

this works, but just for slow moves!!!

How can I move form in Firemonkey?

Comment: You can use `WM_SYSCOMMAND` too. It it's not defined, define it.

Comment: How I can define `WM_SYSCOMMAND`?

Comment: `WM_SYSCOMMAND = $0112` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx

Comment: Thanks, would you answer this question with a part of source code? This is my code that's not work!! on mouse down `ReleaseCapture;
    SendMessage(Form4.Handle, $0112, $F012, 0) ;`

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. I'm not sure what `$F012` is all about. I'm not particular motivated to try to decode magic constants.

Comment: I have a panel on the top of my form, and in its mouse down event trying this code to move the form.
`SC_DRAGMOVE = $F012;`

Comment: @David, I think the only magic in the so called `SC_DRAGMOVE` constant is that MS just forget to include it to the winuser header file (and because of this also document it). I don't think it's magical somehow. sma6871, try the [`code like this`](http://pastebin.com/5i8SSv0z) and optionally move the constants to be common.

Comment: @TLama My problem is the use of `$F012`. Using `SC_DRAGMOVE` is fine. And your code is for VCL. The Q is FMX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the VCL code that you want to replicate is:

```
SendMessage(MyForm.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_DRAGMOVE, 0);
```

then the equivalent for FMX would be:

```
SendMessage(FmxHandleToHWND(MyForm.Handle), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_DRAGMOVE, 0);
```

The reason is that `MyForm.Handle` is an FMX handle. That's not the same as a window handle. You convert to a window handle with `FmxHandleToHWND()`.

You may need to declare a couple of constants:

```
const
  WM_SYSCOMMAND = $0112;
  SC_DRAGMOVE = $F012;
```

Comment: Thanks and the last thing is `uses FMX.Platform.Win` ;-)

Comment: $F012 = (SC_MOVE or HTCAPTION)

Answer (score 11):

What easier is just to use the StartWindowDrag method of the Form. This way it will work in both Windows and MacOS and its only 1 line of code. Like so:

```
procedure TForm4.dragPanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
    Self.StartWindowDrag;
end;
```