# Delphi fmx move borderless form

Tags: macos, delphi

How to make a form move in Delphi FMX also when you move the mouse fast. ?. 
I have tried the code below but when you move the mouse to fast it stop's to work.

[How to drag a borderless FMX form on the screen through another object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197111/how-to-drag-a-borderless-fmx-form-on-the-screen-through-another-object)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move borderless form in Firemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381796/move-borderless-form-in-firemonkey)

Answer (score 1):

Though it's mentioned in the post linked as a comment of OP I think it won't hurt to add it here too, as it's not the accepted answer over there some people searching for this at a later date may miss it. Also make sure it actually is the left mouse button, unless you want to have it drag with other buttons too.

```
procedure TMyForm.DragPanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if (Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft) then StartWindowDrag;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much - does it also work when you move the mouse farst?. Because I did try to make something my self whith mousedown and mousemove but showhow if I did move the mouse to fast it would stop to work.

Comment: It should, but I'd very much advise you to just try it out ... ;)